# Chrome Dev Tools Error Log?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

This is probably a dumb question, but while debugging JavaScript files with breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools, I notice that when an error occurs, the message just flashes in red and I have no idea what it is saying. So for example, when I'm stepping through a function and I encounter a line where the function fails, a red error message displays but flashes so quickly that I can't read it. Is there a setting that I can change to fix this? Or an area where it logs my errors?

Here is a picture of the errors I'm talking about: they just flash and disappear.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a small red icon near the top right corner of the developer tools. Click that and it should show you a list of all the errors. Alternatively, just go to the Console section.

Comment: Do you see the console?

Comment: Yep, I have the console open as a drawer while in the resources tab. I do see the error get logged in there, but it also flashes and disappears. I think I'm getting closer though!

Comment: Errors shouldn't be disappearing from the console. Is your page reloading? Because if the page reloads the console gets cleared.

Comment: Ah okay, so I just need to find a way to prevent the page from reloading. When it encounters the line error it automatically reloads the page.

Comment: I am assuming somewhere in your code you have a JavaScript statement that reloads the page, like `window.location.reload()` or something similar. Commenting that out temporarily should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that this is occurring in a form validation script. I think the form is submitting through and hence the page gets reloaded. My action attribute on the form is a hash right now.

Comment: Yeah, form submits will do that :P.

Comment: Haha, gotcha! Thanks Adosi for the generous help. My solution was to wrap the block where the line was occurring in a try/catch, and I logged the error to the console using catch, while using preventDefault. Cheers, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little checkbox on the console tab called 'Preserve log'. When checked, it will prevent the flashing error problem without having to add additional code to prevent the page reloading.